# how to check if all item of array exist in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I do have have 2 array
the first array is:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "aa"
  }
];

arr2 = [1,3];
```

I want to check if all object.id in arr1 exist in arr2 or not

Comment: Just to let you know, stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Please include your attempt so we can assist you.

Comment: I am also a bit confused, there are answers below that are correct, based on what you have asked. If one of the id's in your array1 are not in the second array, it will return false. Is this the correct behaviour? Because based on your question, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have listed to examples below. One uses Includes, the other uses indexof. Internet explorer does not support includes https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes so if you require support for all browsers, use indexof. See code below.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "aa"
  }
];

var arr2 = [1,3];

// Using Includes
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
 for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if(!arr2.includes(arr1[i].id)) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

// One thing to note, includes is not supported by internet explorer, so you have to use indexof. Example below.
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
 for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i].id) === -1) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

console.log(compareArrays(arr1, arr2));
console.log(compare(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const exists = arr1.reduce((carry, item) => {
  if (carry === false) {
    return carry;
  };
  return arr2.includes(item.id);
});
```

More on reduce here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: thanks for your help but your solution work not exactly like i want

Answer (score -1):

use `every`.

```js
arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "aa"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "aa"
  }
];

arr2 = [1, 3];

console.log(arr1.every(({
  id
}) => arr2.includes(id)));
```